# Exclude certain values from a numeric up down

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I am using C# with VS2013 in .net 4.5.2.

Basically, I have a numeric updown that the user can select certain values from. However, I would like it so that the only selectable values are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12, and multiples of 24. Is there something that can do that, or would it be simpler to just have a ComboBox?

Comment: See the answers to this question for some ways to accomplish this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514400/numericupdown-invalid-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `NumericUpDown` like this

```
class CustomNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    private int currentIndex = 0;
    private decimal[] possibleValues = null;
    public decimal[] PossibleValues
    {
        get
        {
            if (possibleValues == null)
            {
                possibleValues = GetPossibleValues().ToArray();
            }
            return possibleValues;
        }
    }

    public override void UpButton()
    {
        if (base.UserEdit)
        {
            this.ParseEditText();
        }
        var values = PossibleValues;
        this.currentIndex = Math.Min(this.currentIndex + 1, values.Length - 1);
        this.Value = values[this.currentIndex];
    }

    public override void DownButton()
    {
        if (base.UserEdit)
        {
            this.ParseEditText();
        }
        var values = PossibleValues;
        this.currentIndex = Math.Max(this.currentIndex - 1, 0);
        this.Value = values[this.currentIndex];
    }

    private IEnumerable<decimal> GetPossibleValues()
    {
        foreach (var value in new decimal[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12 })
        {
            yield return value;
        }
        for (decimal i = 24; i < Maximum; i += 24)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This screws the  [Acceleration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.accelerations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) feature. And needs but more effort to respond to `Maximum` property changed during runtime.

Also worth noting if `Maximum` value is very large, this will create a huge array. For small values this is fine. To get rid of that array you need your own state machine implementation.

Comment: This is rather lovely! As for the maximum, I was thinking 30 days, so the array would only end up being about 37 values-ish, tops.

Comment: @user3215251 great, then it is not a concern. Cheers..:)

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a combo box, and populate the combobox with if statements embedded inside a for loop

```
for(int I = 0; I < 100; I++)
{ 
    if((I == 1) || (I == 2) || etc.... || (I % 24 == 0))
    {
        //populate combo box with this value
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to validate that the input is in your desired set of numbers.

So.. I would do something like this. It's just a general idea, but should do what you need. number % 24 == 0 will be good for 24, 48, 72, etc..

```
List<int> acceptedValues = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12 };

private void numericUpDown1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int number = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    if (acceptedValues.Contains(number) || (number % 24 == 0))
    {
       // is good
    }
}

private void numericUpDown1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) 
    {
       int number = numericUpDown1.Value;
       if (acceptedValues.Contains(number) || (number % 24 == 0))
       {
          // is good
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My custom class:

```
    class NumericUpdownCustom : NumericUpDown
{
    private decimal[] possibleValues = null;

    public decimal[] PossibleValues
    {
        get
        {
            return possibleValues;
        }
        set
        {
            possibleValues = value;
            FillDefaultValues();
            this.Value = possibleValues.Min();
        }
    }

    public NumericUpdownCustom() : base()
    {
        FillDefaultValues();
        this.Value = PossibleValues.Min();    
    }

    private void FillDefaultValues() {
        if (PossibleValues == null) {
            List<decimal> items = new List<decimal>();
            for (decimal i = this.Minimum; i <= this.Maximum; i++)
            {
                items.Add(i);
            }
            PossibleValues = items.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public override void UpButton()
    {
        if (base.UserEdit)
        {
            this.ParseEditText();
        }

        decimal number = (decimal)this.Value;

        if (PossibleValues.Any(a => a > number))
        {
            this.Value = PossibleValues.Where(w => w > number).Min();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Value = PossibleValues.Max();
        }
    }

    public override void DownButton()
    {
        if (base.UserEdit)
        {
            this.ParseEditText();
        }

        decimal number = (decimal)this.Value;

        if (PossibleValues.Any(a => a < number))
        {
            this.Value = PossibleValues.Where(w => w < number).Max();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Value = PossibleValues.Min();
        }
    }

    public new decimal Value
    {
        get
        {
            decimal desiredValue = base.Value;

            if (!PossibleValues.Contains(desiredValue))
            {
                var nearest = PossibleValues.Aggregate((current, next) => Math.Abs((long)current - desiredValue) < Math.Abs((long)next - desiredValue) ? current : next);
                SetValueWithoutRaisingEvent(nearest);
            }

            return base.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!PossibleValues.Contains(value))
            {
                var nearest = PossibleValues.Aggregate((current, next) => Math.Abs((long)current - value) < Math.Abs((long)next - value) ? current : next);
                base.Value = nearest;
            }
            else
            {
                if (value < this.Minimum)
                {
                    base.Value = this.Minimum;
                }
                else if (value > this.Maximum)
                {
                    base.Value = this.Maximum;
                }
                else
                {
                    base.Value = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetValueWithoutRaisingEvent(decimal value) {
        var currentValueField = GetType().BaseType.GetRuntimeFields().Where(w => w.Name == "currentValue").FirstOrDefault();
        if (currentValueField != null)
        {
            currentValueField.SetValue(this, value);
            this.Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Not fully tested (for example with data bingings), but:

- It works with specified array of values.
- If the possible values are not set, then the normal values will be used between Minimum and Maximum.
- Can change value with typing or programatically. The value will be the nearest value if the possible values array not contains the given value.
- Duplicate ValueChanged events is removed when change value programatically to impossible value.

Problems:

- Value changed event is firing when you set irrelevant value with typing and the control changes this value to the nearest value and this is equal with previous value.

Usage:

- Place the control to the form.
- Set the PossibleValues array:

  NumericUpdownCustom1.PossibleValues = new decimal[] { 1, 10, 20, 33, 55 };